# Creases on render at UV seams, fixed in texture paint mode but in render still

Tags: texturing, normals

I was working with a gun revolver for a game, and I noticed that there were creases on the UV seams when looking from afar.

Close:

[image]

Far:

[image]

EDIT

just to clarify those scratches are intended, I was referring to the crease around the back of the chamber.

EDIT

Also, I did notice tiny little lines of different colors in the same places on  the texture in tex paint mode, but they're barely noticeable and they shouldn't grow when I zoom out.  However, when trying to remove them nothing happens. These are on the seams of the UV.

Comment: What exactly is your question though? You got creases and fixed them in texture paint mode? It's a valid way to do that, I use the clone tool to fix normal maps in texture paint mode.

Comment: I tried the clone tool, and painting over these tiny rivets does nothing. I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Let me rephrase - I fixed the colors that appeared to be causing this. In texture paint mode. In render they are not there anymore FROM CLOSE RANGE. From afar you can clearly see there is a crease.